# Typo3 error 'There is no column with name 't3ver_oid' on table 'tx_news_domain_model_news'.'

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I updated all dependencies according to this [post](https://www.derhansen.de/2019/09/there-is-no-column-with-name-t3ver-oid-on-table.html) but still get the same error.

Since I'm new to TYPO3 I don't know what else I can do.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: First, which TYPO3 version? I had this error once when the dependencies are not correct. It looks like that you extend the news table, the extension where this is done must have a dependency to news, so the loading order of the extensions is respected.
If you have a non-Composer installation this is done in ext_emconf.php, otherwise in composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a composer based typo3 installation you need to add the requirements to composer.json and not ext_emconf.php as in newer typo3 version composer is the only truth in loading order.

and ext_emconf.php is only considered if you running a non composer installation

Comment: I guess this is new behaviour in TYPO3 11 (compared to v10)? Would mean, that all `ext_emconf.php` dependency entries need to be converted to `composer.json` entries?

Comment: Yes, for composer-based installations the composer.json is the source of truth, in fact, ext_emconf.php is in composer-based installation superfluous.